# Get returnKeyType text for UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uikit

I am creating a custom `UIToolBar` to add as `inputAccessoryView` to a `UITextField`, I would like to add a `UIBarButtonItem` on the right side of this toolbar to serve as the return key of this textfield, and the text of this barButtonItem should be the same as the keyboard of that textfield.

My approach was:

```
        let buttonDone =  UIBarButtonItem(title: myTextField.returnKeyType, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(pickerDone)

        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        // toolbar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.items = [space, buttonDone]
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        // setup input
        myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

But with this i get this error:

**Cannot convert value of type 'UIReturnKeyType?' to expected argument type 'String?'**

So, I try something like:

```
title: myTextField.returnKeyType.text
```

But `returnKeyType` doesn't has a `.text` variable or similar...

Is there any way of doing this?
Should I go another way?

Comment: There is no built-in way to convert the `UIReturnKeyType` enum to a string. You will need to write your own code using a `switch` on the all the possible values.

Comment: `UIReturnKeyType` is an `enum` with `rawValue` of type `int`. You can't convert it to `String`. You can write an extension on `UIReturnKeyType` to return a variable which will give the string version of it. But there is no guarantee that you can cover all cases in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to convert the UIReturnKeyType enum to a string. You will need to write your own code using a switch on the all the possible values.

Here's one solution using an extension. Add support for the other values as needed.

```
extension UIReturnKeyType {
    var label: String {
        switch self {
        case .default:
            return "Return"
        case .go:
            return "Go"
        case .done:
            return "Done"
        default:
            return "Enter"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this as:

```
let buttonDone =  UIBarButtonItem(title: myTextField.returnKeyType.label, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(pickerDone)
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this way because in the future it may not support all cases, or support cases that no longer exist.
But it seems that it is currently the best way for what I see, thanks.

Comment: If you fill in all cases and remove the `default:` catch-all, then you don't have to worry about new values until some future when a new value might be added and then your code won't compile so you will know that it needs to be updated.